# Laravel: Give Authorization to Managers and Interns Roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-controller

My application have different roles as **managers interns and accountant**. I have a profile page that is now accesible to all the users (all interns managers and accountant).

Now I want the profile to be accessible only to managers and interns whose profile it is.

For example:- if you are an intern you should be able to see only your profile and your manager should be able to see all the profile of all the interns.

> Here is my **UserProfileController.php**:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\Leave;
use App\Role;
use App\User;
use App\UserRole;


class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [ 'profile']]);
    }
    public function profile($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('user.profile', compact('user') );

    }

}
```

> Here is my route (**web.php**)

```
Route::get('user/profile/{id}', 'UserProfileController@profile')->name('user.profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect time to look into [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#writing-policies). A policy is run **before you reach the action** since you'll assign it as middleware.